Determine the Mode of a group of cells in several columns
My problem is similar to this entry:
How to Determine the Mode of a group of cells
How can I find the modal value if the range to be searched for is not one columns, but in several columns?
Here an example:

Formulas should be used to calculate the values. Thanks in advance!
I have tried to use this formulas but they only work if the category is in one column:
I2:
=COUNTIF(A2:A10,"?*")
J2:
IF(ROWS(J$2:J2)<=$I$2,INDEX($A$2:$A$10,SMALL(IF(LEN($A$2:$A$10)>0,ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS(J$2:J2))),"")
K2:
=IF(ROWS(K$2:K2)<=$I$2,INDEX($E$2:$E$10,MODE(IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET($A$2:$A$10,,,ROW($A$2:$A$10)

Are the categories in two groups (Ref1 and Ref2) as in the link so you need a separate answer for each of them? What version of Excel do you have?

Yes, the categories are in various groups. I need seperate answers for every catergory. My Excel version is 2308

I was able to do the following formula - basically convert the range to unicode characters, then the mode function is available to you, at which point you convert them back to letters.


If you can use groupby (which I find useful), you can try:
=REDUCE({"Group","Mode"},UNIQUE(A2:A12),
 LAMBDA(a,c,
  VSTACK(a,
   HSTACK(c,LET(col,TOCOL(FILTER(D2:F12,A2:A12=c)),
   @SORT(GROUPBY(col,SEQUENCE(ROWS(col)),COUNT,0,0),2,-1))))))


(provided there is a single mode - otherwise you will get the earliest one alphabetically)
